# How to remove this grey deposit from concrete

Tags: concrete

Our house facade has a plint made of concrete with exposed aggregate.
On the corner of the house, the plinth has a greyish deposit on it (see pic).
Since this part is not fully covered by the roof, I think it is caused by exposure to rain.

This deposit is quite hard: I tried power washing, but to no avail.
Any ideas what this is and how to remove it?

[image: Grey deposit on concrete]

Comment: From the photo it looks like cement or mortar that didn't get washed off before it cured.

Comment: +1 for @jwh20 for recognizing the process of “washing” the face of the concrete wall to get an exposed aggregate finish. Make that an answer and I’ll upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried power washing, cement scale remover, a wire brush,... but all without avail.

Turns out it's some sort of lichen and using strong bleach easily removes all of it!

Answer (score 2):

From the photo it looks like cement or mortar that didn't get washed off before it cured.

Comment: You’ll probably need to use muriatic acid on the “cement” in order to remove it now. Start in a test area and see how much acid and elbow grease is required.

Comment: That was my first guess too, so I tried scrubbing with vinegar, but without avail. I'll try something stronger and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Vinegar is not going to remove cured cement or mortar.  You may find it impossible to remove without damaging the underlying surface, which is held together with cement, also.

Comment: What would you suggest to remove it?

Comment: That's my point, I don't believe you can remove it without damaging the panel as well.  But commonly used for this purpose are chemicals such as phosphoric acid or trisodium phosphate.  Either should be available at a local industrial supply house.

Comment: @Dave - "I tried power washing"... with a PW not powerful enough to damage it? - then it ain't gonna work. Graffiti blasting doesn't remove the graffiti, it removes *the part of the building* that has graffiti on it.